# List of public arquive RPC nodes

Tags: rpc, api

Is there a list of active arquive RPC nodes running on the Tezos network?

I'd like to make a request like:

`https://<node>/chains/main/blocks/3000000`

But I wasn't able to find a public node with this information anymore. They all return 404. Using a more recent block level (i.e. `4250000`) works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following RPC nodes' endpoints. All of them works since the genesis block. I will keep updating the answer as I find more full archive nodes.

- TzKt: https://rpc.tzkt.io/mainnet/chains/main/blocks/0
- Tezos Foundation: https://rpc.tzbeta.net/chains/main/blocks/0
- Marigold: https://mainnet.tezos.marigold.dev/chains/main/blocks/0